# How to set the timezone and get the time all in one line of code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Time.zone = 'Hawaii'  # => "Hawaii"
Time.zone.now         # => Wed, 23 Jan 2008 20:24:27 HST -10:00
```

I would like to do something like `Time.zone('Hawaii').now`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Time.now.in_time_zone("Hawaii")
```